# How to simulate web traffic to test performance of a website

Tags: mysql, performance

I have to test a WordPress site performance on an Ubuntu server running on apache2 and mysql, what the best way to simulate web traffic to see how the theme, plugins, database, cpu, and ram is performing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Jmeter's Access Log Sampler:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler

You can use that to replay your Apache logs at various volumes and concurrences.

Comment: Thank you, I'll set this up.